# Retrieve SiteMapNode matching custom attribute using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sitemap, custom-attributes

I am new to LINQ.  I have an ordinary siteMap XML document with custom attributes.  One of these attributes is: id

I would like to use LINQ to retrieve a single node matching the value of the custom attribute (id).

etc.

My attempt at the LINQ looks like this:

```
private SiteMapNode FindNodeById(SiteMapNodeCollection nodes, int siteMapNodeId)
{
    var pageNode = from SiteMapNode node in nodes.Cast<SiteMapNode>()
                   where node["id"] == Convert.ToString(siteMapNodeId)
                   select node;

    return (SiteMapNode)pageNode;
}
```

During debugging, pageNode becomes assigned with:

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<System.Web.SiteMapNode>}
```

And on the return statement an InvalidCastException is thrown:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Web.SiteMapNode]' to type 'System.Web.SiteMapNode'.
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

EDIT: I've re-posted this question in a clearer manner here: [Re-worded Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036029/sequence-contains-no-matching-element-return-sitemapnode-matching-custom-attri)

Thanks to Stefan for putting me on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

You try to cast a `IEnumerable<SiteMapNode>` to a `SiteMapNode`. Use `First` to filter and return one node:

```
return nodes
  .Cast<SiteMapNode>()
  .First(node => node["id"] == Convert.ToString(siteMapNodeId));
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I replaced the code inside of the FindNodeById method with the code you provided.  However, I now receive an InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element.  In fact, it doesn't seem like the lambda expression is coming into play at all.  Even if I change it to use one of the strongly-type attributes (url or title), I still get the InvalidOperationException error.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've done some more testing and indeed the lambda expressions are working, except only for the strongly-typed attributes in the SiteMap XML file (url, title, description), not for the custom ones (id, isHeaderItem etc.)...I'm starting to think that you can't use a custom attribute in a lambda and I shamefully can't find anything on the net about this.

Comment: A bit of an old question, but if only one node is expected to match `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` would be more specific (thus conveying the proper meaning) and additionally ensure you don't have duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

`pageNode` is a *sequence* of nodes.

You want to call `First()` to get the first item in the sequence.