# Sequence contains no matching element - Return SiteMapNode matching custom attribute using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sitemap, custom-attributes

I have a Web.sitemap file using the `siteMapNode` elements in XML.  I have added custom attributes to each tag.  I am trying to extract the value of the custom attribute `id`.

I want to find a single `siteMapNode` in the `SiteMapNodeCollection` which matches the custom attribute `id`.  I am able to achieve this using a `foreach` loop, but I want to use LINQ to make it short and sweet.

--DOESN'T WORK--
The function is as follows:

```
private SiteMapNode FindNodeById(SiteMapNodeCollection nodes, int siteMapNodeId)
{
    return nodes
            .Cast<SiteMapNode>()
            .First(node => node["id"] == Convert.ToString(siteMapNodeId));
}
```

However, I receive an InvalidOperationException => `Sequence contains no matching element`.  If I switch from a custom attribute to default .NET attribute, such as URL (or title), I get the node back without a problem.
For example, this statement works without a problem for a node with the `title` attribute which is set to 'Test':

--WORKS--

```
    private SiteMapNode FindNodeById(SiteMapNodeCollection nodes, int siteMapNodeId)
    {
        return nodes
          .Cast<SiteMapNode>()
          .First(node => node.title == "Test");
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I am missing in order for the custom attribute value to get matched in the `.First` lambda expression?

I appreciate any help.

Have a great weekend!

Craig

Answer (score 1):

Replace First with FirstOrDefault. But if it crashes then it means there are no elements that satisfy the condition, so the result will be null.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried that and I receive a `null` for the node.  Anytime I try to use a custom attribute, nodes are not returned.  The LINQ only seems to work with strongly-typed attributes of the `siteMapNode` elements.

Comment: But you said it works in a foreach loop.. Why can't you just mechanically rewrite it into a linq query?